# Can you spoof the isTrusted value on a js event?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

I want to trigger a click event with isTrusted=true in Chrome (if possible in other browsers that's fine too). How do I do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: Yes only using powershell I was able to surpass it, any ideas on a way to do it through js yet?